# Optimizing the search of a string in a phrases. Don't know which Python structures I need to use

Tags: python, performance, list, dictionary

I have a file containing several words followed by an integer (it's weight):

```
home 10
house 15
village 20
city 50
big 15
small 5
pretty 10
...
```

and so on.

I need to weight some phrases using, if they match, its words and those contained into the previous file.

"I live in a house in a big city" this phrase weight 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 15 + 0 + 0 + 10 + 50 = 75

It's my first approach using Python even if I have a good experience using C: the difficult I'm experiencing is that I'm not able to reach the required performance because I'm not able to use the right Python structure in the right way.
I was able to weight correctly the phrases but using several "for" and a function call just like a I did using C.

```
def weight_word(word, words_file):
    fp = open(words_file)
    weight = 0
    line = fp.readline()
    while line:
    # One method I discovered to parse the line where there's
    # a word, a tab and its weight
    left, tab_char, right = line.partition('\t')
    if re.match(re.escape(word), left, re.I):
            # The previous re.match didn't guarantee an exact match so I need
            # even to control their lenghts...
        if len(word) == len(left): 
            weight = right
            break
        line = fp.readline()
    fp.close
    return float(weight)

def main():
    my_dict = {"dont parse me":"500", "phrase":"I live in a house in a small city", "dont parse me again":"560"}
    my_phrase = my_dict["phrase"].split()
    phrase_weight = 0
    for word in iter(my_phrase):
        phrase_weight = phrase_weight + weight_word(word, sys.argv[1])
    print "The weight of phrase is:" + str(phrase_weight)
```

Now I have just discovered something that could be useful for my case but I don't know how to use it appropriately:

```
def word_and_weight(fp):
    global words_weight
    words_weight = {}
    for line in fp:
        word, weight = line.split('\t')
        words_weight[word] = int(weight)
```

How can I avoid the previous for and the call to my function for each word of my phrase and how could instead use the last kind of "array" indexed by word?
I'm now a little bit confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping is a dictionary:

```
>>> d = {'foo': 32, 'bar': 64}
>>> d['bar']
64
```

To get the weight of a sentence, you can add up the weights of the individual words:

```
weight = 0

for word in sentence.split():
    weight += weights[word]
```

Or with regex:

```
for word in re.finditer(r'(\w+)', sentence):
    ...
```

You can use `sum` and a generator to make it more concise:

```
weight = sum(weights[word] for word in sentence.split())
```

If some words aren't in your dictionary, you can use `dict.get()`'s second argument to return `0` in case a word isn't in there:

```
weight = sum(weights.get(word, 0) for word in sentence.split())
```

Comment: Did you remove the mapping-file parsing again?  Why?  Seemed okay.

Comment: @Alfe: It was in OP's code, so there's really no reason to keep it here.

Answer (score 1):

Your first pass algorithm is opening and parsing your words file for every word in your phrase, which is obviously bad regardless of language.  Your `word_and_weight` function is less bad, but you don't need global variables.  Assuming you have my_dict set up the way it is for a reason, and don't mind the lack of input protection in your weights file, I would do this as something like this:

```
import fileinput

def parse_word_weights():
    word_weights = {}
    for line in fileinput.input():
        word, weight = line.strip().split('\t')
        word_weights[word] = int(weight)
    return word_weights

def main():
    word_weights = parse_word_weights()

    my_dict = {"dont parse me":"500", "phrase":"I live in a house in a small city", "dont parse me again":"560"}
    my_phrase = my_dict["phrase"].split()
    phrase_weight = sum((word_weights.get(word, 0) for word in my_phrase))
    print "The weight of phrase is:" + str(phrase_weight)
```

This uses the fileinput standard library to standardize file input - it's a long way from the only option, but it's very convenient.  The sum call is running over a generator expression that will lazily evaluate the word lookup for each word in turn.

There's nothing really wrong with an explicit for loop adding up the phrase weight, but the sum call is more idiomatic.  If you do stick with a for loop, you don't need the iter call on my_phrase - the output from split can be directly iterated over.

Comment: I really appreciate all of your suggestions: I didn't realize I could return my dict instead of using a global variable and I know open and close a file for every phrases it was a bad decision. I'm embarrassed for the Python's power and its structures... I realized I had to use the so called list or dict comprehensions but the syntax is not so easy to follow: or using the right function like you both did word_weights.get(word, 0). I'm really a newbie and I would like to continue to use this powerful language.

Comment: : can you suggest two books to buy ? I read the following link https://developers.google.com/edu/python and the Python documentation but just from a C developer. So I read them just to solve the above problem: now I want to read a manual from A to Z and understand where, when and how to use different structures in different contexts. Thanks, Denny

Comment: It has been too long since I learned Python for me to really recommend a book, but this free online course gets a lot of recommendations from other people: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/